# How to count number that contains 3 between 1 and N where N is the given input?

Tags: c

Given a number N, I wish to count the number of 3's that occur in the 
 the range 1 - N.

```
int N;
int cnt = 0;
scanf("%d", &N);

for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    if (i < 30) {
        if (i % 10 == 3)
            cnt++;
    }
    else {
        while (i > 0) {
            if (i % 10 == 3) {
                cnt++;
            }
            i = (i / 10);
        }
    }
}
printf("%d", cnt);
```

When my input is between 1 to 29 this program work correctly but when the input is beyond 30 the program gives me a wrong answer.

Comment: Your inner while decrements the variable `i` which is used to control the outer for loop.  So, every time `i` gets to 30, you bring it back to 0, and start the process over again.

Comment: What is this program supposed to do? What is it doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to count each number containing at least one "3" or do you want to count each digit "3". Does "33" count once or twice?

Comment: thanks for help. 
I am sorry that I have not been able to ask the question correctly because I am not familiar with how to use the community yet.
all of the answers is nice to me.
next time, i will Meticulously write the question.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same variable for the outer for loop and the inner while loop.
You need to use a different variable for the inner while loop. 
With the variable `j` controlling the while loop, your program will look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int N, j;
    int cnt = 0;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        if (i < 30) {
            if (i % 10 == 3)
                cnt++;
        }
        else {
            j = i;
            while (j > 0) {
                if (j % 10 == 3) {
                    cnt++;
                }
                j = (j / 10);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", cnt);
    return -1; 
}
```

Output:

```
>a.exe
30
4

>a.exe
33
8
```